# Best way to override a class's dependency for a unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

tl;dr Trying to understand the right way to test a class but need to override some members of a dependency. Below I described my thought process on trying to subclass this dependency but perhaps I should just reimplement the interface of the dependency and skip trying to override and subclass the dependency altogether?

---

Ok I am trying to unit test a class that relies on an object that calls out. I want to make that object's properties mutable so I can change them during the test rather than having it call the network. I think it's tricky because the parent class has only a getter on the property in question. I am a bit new to C# and would like confirmation/correction of my reasoning so far.

I have an interface:

```cs
public interface ISettings
{
    bool IsFooEnabled { get; }
}
```

And a class

```cs
public class Settings : ISettings
{
    public bool IsFooEnabled => bool.Parse(DoNetworkStuff());
}
```

And I have made a this class in my test:
Fig 1:

```cs
public class TestSettings : Settings
{
    public bool IsFooEnabled = true;
}
```

And I want the overridden object to be passed into a object's constructor since normally `SomeObject` expects an `ISettings` object:

```cs
public void Test()
{
    TestSettings s = new TestSettings();
    s.IsFooEnabled = true;
    SomeObject s = new SomeObject(s);
}
```

So the test fails because the `DoNetworkStuff()` is returning `null`:
Fig 1.1:

```
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')
  Stack Trace: 
    Boolean.Parse(String value)
    Settings.get_IsFooEnabled() line 113
```

I think it's because

Same error with:
Fig 2:

```cs
public class TestSettings : Settings
{
    public bool IsFooEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

and
Fig 3:

```cs
public class TestSettings : Settings
{
        public bool IsFooEnabled => false;
}
```

and
Fig 4:

```cs
public class TestSettings : Settings
{
        public bool IsFooEnabled = false;
}
```

All return the error of Fig 1.1. Which means `Settings.IsFooEnabled` isn't being overridden, it is still trying to call out and getting null. Which I was confused about because I thought in the subclass, the subclass's definition takes precedence. But then the expected type is `Settings`, so I think the `TestSettings` `IsFooEnabled` is being ignored.

But this WORKS:
Fig 4:

```cs
public class TestSettings : Settings
{
    public override bool IsFooEnabled => false;
}
```

But then I have to change settings to be virtual or else it complains, which makes sense because I cannot override without a virtual in the parent class:
Fig 5:

```cs
public class Settings : ISettings
{
    public virtual bool IsFooEnabled => bool.Parse(DoNetworkStuff());
}
```

I also tried overriding the property by itself:
Fig 6:

```cs
public class TestSettings : Settings
{
    public override bool IsFooEnabled = false;
}
```

But got this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0106  The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item  Foo.Unit.Tests  Foo.cs  33  N/A
```

Which makes sense because you can't override a property.
I think overall I am a bit confused why a property declaration doesn't override the parent class's property expression. I think the fact that the parent has a get; means that it has to be another getter overriding it, it can't just be a property?

Ultimate question, is this the right way to go about the situation? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding some part of C#'s inheritance?
Sorry for being long winded but was really trying to understand what was going on here.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and is ultimately a design issue as the target/subject class, if it was following SOLID principles , would be dependent on an abstraction `ISettings`  instead of a concretion ie:`Settings`, which would make the whole problem of trying to override the member mute since it is no longer tightly coupled to implementation details.

Comment: OK that was another option I didn't write but yes, just implementing the interface and all it's members seems to be an easier way though I would have to implement all members of the class if there were many.

Comment: @Nkosi - "moot", not "mute".

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you do not want `TestSettings` to directly implement `ISettings`, because you would need to implement a ton of other members as well.

One way to tackle this, is "partial mocking". Many mocking libraries are providing that. Using a mocking library is usually a better idea than "manual" mocking.

Apart from that: You **can** override a property. The case that is not working is not a property, but just a field. The following variants should work just fine (they are just different ways to define a property):

```cs
public class TestSettings : Settings
{
    public override bool IsFooEnabled
    {
        get;
    }
}

public class TestSettings : Settings
{
    public override bool IsFooEnabled => true;
}
```

This is not working, because it is a field, not a property which are different things in C#.

```cs
public class TestSettings : Settings
{
    public override bool IsFooEnabled = true; // syntax error
}
```

Comment: oh thanks! today I learned the difference between a field, property, and method! can the IsFooEnabled property you described above in TestSettings also have a setter? i.e. `{get;set;}`

Comment: Yes. This is exactly how you would define it.